# polymorphism and association relationship in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I have classes Foo and Bar that implement an interface IFooBar. I have two other classes DerivedFoo and DerivedBar, who inherit from another class Base. IFooBar got a method that use Base as parameter.

I would like Foo and Bar to use Base or DerivedFoo/DerivedBar depending on the type.

To give you a more visual exemple (C#) :

```
public abstract class Base : SuperBase
{

}

public class DerivedFoo : Base
{
   public string FooProperty {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedBar : Base
{
   public int FooProperty {get; set;}
}


public interface IFooBar
{
   Base Update(Base toUpdate);
}

public class Foo : IFooBar
{
   public Base Update(DerivedFoo toUpdate)
   {
     toUpdate.FooProperty = "X";
     return toUpdate;
   }
}



public class Bar: IFooBar
    {
       public Base Update(DerivedBar toUpdate)
       {
         toUpdate.BarProperty = 42;
         return toUpdate;
       }
    }
```

This implementation fails, as you expected, because i don't implement interface properly. If i implement it properly (replacing DerivedFoo type by Base type) I can't find my property FooProperty/BarProperty. Do you have any tip to achieve the behaviour i seek ?

EDIT : Implementing Aleksey L. solution, i would like an list of IFooBar, i use an ObservableCollection.

Previously (before use of genericity), i was doing (in another class) :

```
 private ObservableCollection<IFooBar> m_foobarlist;

        public ObservableCollection<IFooBar> FooBarList
        {
            get
            {
                return m_foobarlist;
            }
            set
            {
                m_foobarlist= value;
                // other work
            }
        }
```

In constructor :

```
 FooBarList = new ObservableCollection<IFooBar>
            {
                new Foo(),
                new Bar()
            };
```

I tried to use the changed classes after Aleksey tips :

private ObservableCollection> m_foobarlist;

```
        public ObservableCollection<IFooBar<Base>> FooBarList
        {
            get
            {
                return m_foobarlist;
            }
            set
            {
                m_foobarlist= value;
                // other work
            }
        }
```

In constructor :

```
 FooBarList = new ObservableCollection<IFooBar<Base>>
            {
                new Foo(),
                new Bar()
            };
```

But this doesn't seem to work ('Cannot convert Footo IFooBar' 'Cannot convert Bar to IFooBar')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
public interface IFooBar<T> where T : Base
{
    T Update(T toUpdate);
}

public class Foo : IFooBar<DerivedFoo>
{
    public DerivedFoo Update(DerivedFoo toUpdate)
    {
        toUpdate.FooProperty = "X";
        return toUpdate;
    }
}

public class Bar : IFooBar<DerivedBar>
{
    public DerivedBar Update(DerivedBar toUpdate)
    {
        toUpdate.BarProperty = 42;
        return toUpdate;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**. Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but in order to have a list of `IFooBar` you could define a base class above this interface:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    Base Update(Base toUpdate);
}

public abstract class BaseFooBar<T> : IFooBar where T : Base
{
    protected abstract T UpdateDerived(T Base);

    public Base Update(Base toUpdate)
    {
        var derived = toUpdate as T;
        if (derived == null)
        {
            //not expected type. decide what you want to do in this case. throw exception?
        }

        return UpdateDerived(derived);
    }
}

public class Foo : BaseFooBar<DerivedFoo>
{
    protected override DerivedFoo UpdateDerived(DerivedFoo toUpdate)
    {
...
```

Comment: EDIT : How would you declare and initialise an ObservableCollection of IFooBar with this strategy ?

Comment: could you elaborate  on use case?

Comment: I edited the original post, let me know if it's not clear or not what you expected.

Comment: I ended up using your update as inspiration for another method that require very little changes in the original code, but i don't use genericity.

Answer (score 0):

Aleksey method seem good, but i ended up using this trick :

```
public class Foo : IFooBar
{
   public Base Update(Base toUpdate)
   {
     var fooInstance = toUpdate as Foo;
     if(fooInstance == null)
     {
        return null;
     }
     fooInstance.FooProperty = "X";
     return fooInstance ;
   }
}
```